# jQuery select element that matches one of the classnames of another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a couple of elements, one of which may have any number of classnames - one of these will be common.

eg:

```
<div class='div1 someClassname someOtherClassname'></div>
<div id='container'>
  <div class='div1'>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I have an event that fires on `.someClassname` but I need to do something with `#container .div1`. How do I select `#container .div1` using only what I can glean from `.someClassname` when an event fires on it?

Here's the kind of thing I'm experimenting with:

```
$('.someClassname').click(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class');  // 'div1 someClassname someOtherClassname'
    var otherElem = $('#container').children().filter(classes); //empty jQuery object
});
```

I can't really parse the classnames as I won't know the specific class I'm looking for, or the classes that I'm *not* looking for as the number and names change depending.

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd say you're on the right track. The problem `filter` gives an empty result is that your classes string consists of classnames, but filter wants class-selecotrs (with the dot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$('.someClassname').click(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ").join(",.");
    alert(classes);
    $('.'+classes).not(this).each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
    });

});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3rVjN/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.someClassname').click(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
   $.each(classes , function(index, value) { 
        console.log($('#container').find("."+value));
});

});
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/TaBd7/)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you will need to use `split` on the classes and format your selector with the dots and commas as necessary. Give it a go, if you still struggle I will post some test code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost got it right. Just `.split` the `classes` var with , prepend a `.` to each array element and then join the array back with `,` so you get `.div1, .otherclassname, etc.`. You can use this string as your selector.

This is assuming you want logical OR regarding classes. Otherwise (if you want AND), don't join with `,`, just stick the elements together.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't abuse `class` for this.

Add an extra attribute, e.g. HTML5's `data-target="div1"` to the `.someClassName` elements.

```
<div data-target="div1" class="div1 someClassname someOtherClassname"></div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="div1">
  </div>
</div>
```

and then in the code:

```
$('.someClassname').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var other = $('#container').children('.' + target);
});
```

If there are no actual CSS styles associated with `div1` then I would suggest not using styles at all, and put an `id` tag on the target div - it'll work faster to match by ID than to match by class.

Comment: I agree with you - I use jquery's `data()` method elsewhere for keeping track of this kind of stuff normally. however i find myself needing to do this nonetheless

Comment: @jammypeach do you not know when you create the div exactly which "other" class is the one that's going to be "common" ?

Comment: yes, but there are 36 of them and they are numbered - so I was looking for a better way to programatically figure out which one to use. Also they do have styles associated - but I think you're probably right in that from a best practise perspective, data attributes would be better.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you're looking for:

```
    $('.someClassname').click(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class');  // 'div1 someClassname someOtherClassname' 

    var arr = classes.split(" ");
    var filter = [];              

    $.each(arr, function(index, item){
        filter.push("."+item)
    })                      

    var filterStr = filter.join(",")

    var otherElem = $('#container').children().filter(filterStr);  
});
```

The mistake you were having is that classes is a string of classnames.
jQuery's .filter() method accepts a selector.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issues a few days ago. This worked for me:

```
// all your element classes 
allClasses = $('yourElement').attr("class").split(/\s+/);

// retrieve desired classes
for (var j = 0; j < allClasses.length; j++) {
   if (allClasses[j] === 'class1' || allClasses[j] === 'class2' || allClasses[j] === 'class3' ) {
    classes = classes+" "+allClasses[j]
    }
   }        
console.log(classes)
```

I use this if I want to pull class1,2,3 out of the element, which can contain any number of classes with unkown names.

Maybe helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should help:

```
var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/);
var obj = $();
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) { 
    obj = obj.add($("#container ." + classes[i]));
}
```

Now *obj* should contain your object